# Falling with same acceleration and meaning of gravity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, curvature, equivalence-principle

My question is what does falling with **same** acceleration has to do with what Einstein concluded concerning the gravity in terms of the curvature?

Comment: if everything not under a force moves similarly then it is a geometric thing, right?

Comment: What hyportnex said is correct. Everything that falls *freely*, i.e. has no force acting on it, just gravity (not regarded as a force in this context), falls at the same rate. Einstein concluded this must be an intrinsic property of the space in which things are falling. This question arises in mathematics in terms  of differential geometry. Hence gravity is a geometric effect.

Comment: How come the force concept is ditched here? I mean Hartle had written the term "gravitational field". I know and understand that in GR gravity is not a force, but that is a conclusion. @0celo7

Comment: @PhilosophicalPhysics Change "no force acting on it" to "no forces other than gravity." The conclusion is the same.

Comment: Ok, then why is force not regarded as a force here? Because in GR, it is not considered a force. Again this is a conclusion. What I am trying to understand is why falling with same acceleration leads to the fact that gravity is geomerized. You are answering me starting with the latter part of my previous sentence (thus the conclusion I am trying to reach). @0celo7

Comment: @hyportnex Do you agree with what I have discussed with 0celo7?

Comment: in classical physics force acting on a body moves it with acceleration and so does act gravity, too but there is a difference: all other causes (forces) act differently somewhat on different things, e.g., positive/negative charges, S/N magnets, sticky glue, slippery teflon, pressure, friction, etc., but gravity does not care, all bodies behave the same against it as if it was not "physical" or "material" but rather "geometrical" being in the nature of space(+time).

Comment: aha, so the word "same" in the quoted paragraph above made all the difference you mean? @hyportnex

Comment: same, yes (but this is just *my* interpretation of the equivalence priciple and its consequences and i am only an amateur)

Comment: It's not regarded as a force because it's an intrinsic property of spacetime. In classical mechanics, a force is defined as something on the other side of $ma=$. In GR, gravity is not on the other side of this equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement that:

> all bodies fall with the same acceleration in a gravitational field

is the [weak equivalence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle), which has [been experimentally tested](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle#Tests_of_the_weak_equivalence_principle) and so far found to be true. So your question is equivalent to asking how the WEP leads naturally to a metric theory of gravity. However I don't think there is a simple and intuitive way to explain this. It seems obvious to us nerds, but rather less so to the non-GR heads.

One way of grasping the situation is to imagine two observers both starting at the equator and heading due north at constant speed. Because the surface of the Earth is curved the two observers will converge with each other (and meet at the North pole) even though both observers start parallel and just move in a straight line at constant speed. This is just due to the curvature of the Earth and the mass of the observers make no difference. The *acceleration* of the observers towards each other is given by the geodesic equation:

$$ {d^2 x^\mu \over d\tau^2} + \Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta} {dx^\alpha \over d\tau} {dx^\beta \over d\tau} = 0 $$

where the parameters $\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}$ are only dependant on the curvature of the Earth's surface. Note that the mass of the observers does not appear in this equation, and we wouldn't expect it to.

In motion on a sphere there are only two coordinates, longitude and latitude, but a metric theory of gravity extends the geodesic equation to three spatial and one time coordinate, as well as specifying how the parameters $\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}$ are related to any mass present. The result is that the [four-acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-acceleration) is independant of the mass of the object, which is where we started.

**Response to comment:**

The geodesic equation applies to any metric theory. I introduced it to describe motion on the surface of a sphere, but it describes motion in curved spacetime just as it describes motion on a sphere. All you need is the correct form for the parameters $\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}$ used in the equation.

These parameters are called [Christoffel symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols) (of the second kind) and they can be calculated from the [metric tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor_(general_relativity)). So if you're trying to describe how some object moves in spacetime the key thing is to find the correct metric tensor. And this is exactly what Einstein's equation does. It relates the metric tensor to an object called the [stress-energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) that describes how matter and energy is distributed.

So the process is (1) work out the metric tensor using Einstein's equation, (2) calculate the Christoffel symbols and (3) solve the geodesic equation. That's what I mean by *specifying how the parameters $\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}$ are related to any mass present*.

I should note that in principle there can be any number of different metric theories of gravity, and they would differ from each other in step (1). General relativity uses the Einstein equation to calculate the metric, but you can have other theories using a different equation instead. However Einstein's equation turns out to be a very natural choice, and of course when we test it experimentally [it gives the correct predictions](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.7377). That hasn't stopped people suggesting other metric theories e.g. [Brans-Dicke theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brans%E2%80%93Dicke_theory).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have one question: What do you mean by the sentence "as well as specifying how the parameters $\Gamma^{\mu}_{\alpha\beta }$ are related to any mass present."? It is a bit unclear to me.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. Last thing so I could grasp the big picture. You also added that " Note that the mass of the observers does not appear in this equation, and we wouldn't expect it to." Why wouldn't you expect it to? I have read in some other thread here that the second term in the geodesic equation above is considered inertial acceleration as it is generalization of the motion of free particle in Minkowski space upon a general coordinate transformation. So - excuse me if this turns out to naive - but shouldn't we rather expect the mass to appear?

Comment: @PhilosophicalPhysics: I introduced the geodesic equation to describe the acceleration towards each other of two vehicles both headed due North. It doesn't matter whether these are two bicycles or two tanks, the acceleration will be the same. That's why we wouldn't expect the mass to affect the motion.

Comment: Hello, John. I have two questions on your answer. 1. Are you relating the fact that the accelerations exist although each of the velocities (on their own) are constant to the idea that velocity vector changes along the way? 2. Concerning the geodesic equation you presented. You placed this in order to explain your answer, but I am thinking now that the geodesic equation is the result of formulating GR, wasn't it? So, OP was asking why did WEP lead to "GR", however in your explanation, you presented a result of GR. (Or is it that the concept of Geodesic equation was before GR?) Thanks!

Comment: @Beyond-formulas: I don't understand what you are asking in your first question. Maybe it would be worth expanding and posting as a new question. Re the second question: the geodesic equation predated GR - I'm not sure who first wrote it down but it stems from the work of Riemann who died in 1866 fifty years before Einstein formulated GR.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the concept of an inertial frame: in such a frame, all laws of nature take their simplest form; in particular, an inertial frame is a frame in which Newton's Laws (or their Special-Relativistic equivalent) hold: an object on which no external force acts will either remain at rest or continue to move at a constant velocity. Any acceleration on the object is caused only by forces originating from external sources, *not* by the choice of frame (i.e. there are no fictitious forces).

This also means that all inertial frames are equivalent: the laws of physics are identical in every inertial frame, so there is no preferred frame of reference. Furthermore, Special Relativity tells us that all inertial frames should be moving at a constant velocity with respect to each other, because an accelerating frame would introduce a fictitious force. Finally, according to Special Relativity, any inertial frame can describe the entire spacetime.

However, gravitational fields cause a contradiction in Special Relativity. Take for example an astronaut who's inside a spacecraft with no windows and no boosters. Would the astronaut be able to tell if the spacecraft is orbiting the Earth, or orbiting another planet, or moving freely in outer space far away from any celestial object? No, a gravitational field has the same effect on every object inside the spacecraft. Everything in the spacecraft will be weightless, and the astronaut cannot conduct an experiment on board to determine where he is. As far as he knows, he might not be in a gravitational field at all. In other words, his spacecraft is an inertial frame.

But this leads to a contradiction in Special Relativity, because if you take two astronauts, each in their own spacecraft, then they will in general not be moving at a constant velocity with respect to each other (they could even be orbiting different planets), violating the property of inertial frames in Special Relativity.

The solution is that a gravitational field causes spacetime to curve: in a curved spacetime, inertial observers move on geodesics, which are a generalisation of straight lines in flat spacetime. On large scales, geodesics are curved paths, but on small scales a geodesic reduces to a straight line and Special Relativity holds to a good approximation. This means that inertial frames are only defined in small regions of space, where differences in gravitational fields are too small to have an effect. This solves the paradox: each astronaut resides in his own, locally defined, inertial frame. But there is no global inertial frame that connects them, so they do not move at constant velocity with respect to each other.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this but my question was not about where did the idea of giving gravity a geometric flavor come from. It was about how did it specifically result from the fact ***that all bodies fall with the same acceleration in a gravitational field***. I can listen to many stories written in different books about the origin of gravity as geometry. However, I want to understand the very quote above in my question because this is the book assigned to me to read.

Comment: @PhilosophicalPhysics Because nearby objects experience the same acceleration in a gravitational field, they move with constant velocity with respect to each other. So, from the point of view of a falling object, looking at the other objects, Newton's laws hold. This is why the astronaut in the spacecraft concludes that he's in an inertial frame.

Comment: Ok, where is the geometric meaning of gravity in what you said last?

Comment: @PhilosophicalPhysics Let's clarify something: all objects fall with the same acceleration in a *constant* gravitational field. But a real gravitational field isn't constant everywhere, it's only approximately constant within a small region, like a spacecraft. So a spacecraft is a local inertial frame, and second spacecraft in a *different* region of the gravitational field will be another local inertial frame. But those two spacecraft will be accelerating with respect to each other. Two inertial frames cannot accelerate with respect to each in a flat spacetime, therefore spacetime is curved.